# Multiple pattern for one action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am working on MVC 5 routing.  I want to use just 1 mapping  for different URLs;

For example, If the user write  as Prodcut,Producto and Urun like below:

> **www.blabla.com/Product/1**
>
> **www.blabla.com/Urun/1**
>
> **www.blabla.com/Producto/1**

...then will send this request same Action of Product.

Is this possible to make a defination like below code?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Page",
            "Product/{id} | Producto/{id} | Urun/{id}", //This row not working
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ShowProduct" , id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            constraints: new { id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9ğüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_-.]+$" }
        );
```

Comment: What is "Product" and what is "1"? I'm assuming Product/Urun/Producto are not methods in your controller or are they controllers?

Comment: @gilliduck they will present the action. I've included the trick in my answer

Comment: Yes - just using `{controller}/{id}` but then you because your constraint for `{id}` would also match say `/Product/Details` you would then need to create routes for all your other actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better is create multiple route but you can play with constraints

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Page",
        "{name}/{id},
        defaults: new {
           controller = "Product", 
           action = "ShowProduct",
           id = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        constraints: new {
           id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9ğüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_-.]+$",
           name = "Product|Producto|Urun"
        }
    );
```

Comment: That is it.... :)) I want to find just this solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note : Yes its better the create multiple route but I think If you use multiple language for your web site, then you must keep your controller and Route count on minimum. Thanks again.

Comment: And this would also match just any other method on those controllers and go to the wrong method (e.g. `/Product/Index`, `Product/Edit` etc)